# ASH variable indirect reference

Tags: unix, shell

I'm trying to port a script from BASH to ASH (Almquist SHell) and am running into a problem with indirect references. The following function

```
cmd() {
    # first argument is the index to print (ie label)
    arg=$1
    # ditch the first argument
    shift
    # print the label (via indirect reference)
    echo "${!arg}"
}
```

should produce the following output

```
cmd 1 one two three
one
cmd 2 one two three
two
cmd 3 one two three
three
```

This works as expected under BASH, but generates a "syntax error: Bad substitution" when run under ASH (or DASH). Should this work? If not, is there an alternative to using indirect references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `eval`:

```
cmd() {
    arg=$1
    shift
    eval "echo \$$arg"
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I came up with just after posting
    echo "$(eval echo \$$arg)"