# How to get a variable value if variable name is stored as string?

Tags: string, bash

How can I retrieve a bash variable value if I have the variable name as string?

```
var1="this is the real value"
a="var1"
Do something to get value of var1 just using variable a.
```

#### Context:

I have some AMI's ([Amazon Machine Image](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)) and I want to fire up a few instances of each AMI. As soon as they finish booting, I want to setup each instance according to its AMI type. I don't want to bake lots of scripts or secret keys inside any AMI so I prepared a generalized startup script and I put it on [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3) with a publicly accessible link. In rc.local I put small piece of code which fetches the startup script and executes it. This is all I have in the AMIs. Then each AMI accesses a common configuration script which is applicable to all AMIs and special setup scripts for each. These scripts are private and require a signed URL to access them.

So now, when I fire an instance of an AMI (my_private_ami_1), I pass a signed URL for one more file presented on S3 which contains signed URL for all private scripts in terms of key/value pair.

```
config_url="http://s3.amazo.../config?signature"
my_private_ami_1="http://s3.amazo.../ami_1?signature"
...
```

When the startup script runs, it downloads the above file and `source`'s it. Then it checks for its AMI type and picks the correct setup script for itself.

```
ami\_type=GET AMI TYPE #ex: sets ami\_type to my\_private\_ami\_1
setup\_url=GET THE SETUP FILE URL BASED ON AMI\_TYPE # this is where this problem arises
```

So now I can have a generic code which can fire instances irrespective of their AMI types and instances can take care of themselves.

Answer (score 410, accepted):

You can use `${!a}`:

```
var1="this is the real value"
a="var1"
echo "${!a}" # outputs 'this is the real value'
```

This is an example of indirect [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> The basic form of parameter expansion is `${parameter}`. The value of 
>   `parameter` is substituted.
>
> If the first character of `parameter` is an exclamation point (!), it
>   introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the
>   variable formed from the rest of `parameter` as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of `parameter` itself.

Comment: This works for me in OSX bash, but not debian?  On debian I get `Bad substitution` error.

Comment: @23inhouse Are you running your script using `/bin/sh`? If so, try using `/bin/bash` instead. From Debian Squeeze onwards, `/bin/sh` was changed to be a [symlink for `dash` instead of `bash`](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell#Default_.2Fbin.2Fsh_shell). `dash` doesn't support this particular syntax and will output a `Bad substitution` error.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for a variable name that belongs to an array?

Comment: Works on ubuntu with bash

Comment: what is he name of this operation? (want to read about it further more)

Comment: @DoronShai This is an example of indirect parameter expansion, documented in the Bash Reference Manual at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: I also get `syntax error: bad substitution` with ash, is there an ash equivalent of that?

Comment: @Maxim according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014604/5981) you can use `eval "echo \$$a"` with ash.

Comment: Wow! I almost thought this is not possible. How do you guys know this stuff?

Comment: This tripped me up for a bit so I thought I'd share. If you do this, even in bash, all in one line such as `a="hi" b="a" echo "${!b}"` then it won't work. If you break out the declarations of a and be on to separate lines, each as a single command then it does work. It seems like the variable expansion requires the variable be declared in a higher scope or something.

Comment: @justin.m.chase you need a semicolon after each one

Comment: Oh, neat, this even works in conjunction with other variable expansions like `${!a+x}` (even though it looks so wrong).

Comment: this doesn't work in zsh. But `eval "echo \$$a"` works fine.

Answer (score 44):

```
X=foo
Y=X
eval "Z=\$$Y"
```

sets `Z` to `foo`.

Comment: under Linux-Bash: `number=1
eval "Z=zuzu_\$number"
echo "$Z"` the Result is displaying:  **zuzu_1**

Answer (score 26):

For my fellow zsh users, the way to accomplish the same thing as the accepted answer is to use:

```bash
echo ${(P)a} # outputs 'this is the real value'
```

It is appropriately called [*Parameter name replacement*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags). Also works with variables stored in arrays.

> This forces the value of the parameter name to be interpreted as a
> further parameter name, whose value will be used where appropriate.
> Note that flags set with one of the typeset family of commands (in
> particular case transformations) are not applied to the value of name
> used in this fashion.
>
> If used with a nested parameter or command substitution, the result of
> that will be taken as a parameter name in the same way. For example,
> if you have ‘foo=bar’ and ‘bar=baz’, the strings ${(P)foo},
> ${(P)${foo}}, and ${(P)$(echo bar)} will be expanded to ‘baz’.
>
> Likewise, if the reference is itself nested, the expression with the
> flag is treated as if it were directly replaced by the parameter name.
> It is an error if this nested substitution produces an array with more
> than one word. For example, if ‘name=assoc’ where the parameter assoc
> is an associative array, then ‘${${(P)name}[elt]}’ refers to the
> element of the associative subscripted ‘elt’.

Answer (score 15):

Modified my search keywords and Got it :).

```
eval a=\$$a
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Take care using eval since this may allow accidential excution of code through values in `${Y}`.  See my addition in the answer of the user "anon".

Comment: This is the only working answer.  Ironic that it is your own!

Answer (score 15):

In bash 4.3+, you can use `declare -n`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var="this is the real value"
var_name="var"

declare -n var_ref=$var_name
echo "${var_ref}"
```

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue with arrays, here is how to do it if you're manipulating arrays too :

```
array_name="ARRAY_NAME"
ARRAY_NAME=("Val0" "Val1" "Val2")

ARRAY=$array_name[@]
echo "ARRAY=${ARRAY}"
ARRAY=("${!ARRAY}")
echo "ARRAY=${ARRAY[@]}"
echo "ARRAY[0]=${ARRAY[0]}"
echo "ARRAY[1]=${ARRAY[1]}"
echo "ARRAY[2]=${ARRAY[2]}"
```

This will output :

```
ARRAY=ARRAY_NAME[@]
ARRAY=Val0 Val1 Val2
ARRAY[0]=Val0
ARRAY[1]=Val1
ARRAY[2]=Val2
```

Comment: +1 for this is the only correct answer for array, to make it clearer, the string must have `[@]` suffix to obtain the full array.

Answer (score 2):

In bash 4.3, the '-v' test for set variables was introduced. At the same time, 'nameref' declaration was added. These two features together with the indirection operator (!) enable a simplified version of the previous example:

```
get_value()
{
  declare -n var_name=$1
  if [[ -v var_name ]]
  then
    echo "${var_name}"
  else
    echo "variable with name <${!var_name}> is not set"
  fi
}

test=123
get_value test
123

test="\$(echo \"something nasty\")"
get_value test
$(echo "something nasty")

unset test
get_value test
variable with name <test> is not set
```

As this approach eliminates the need for 'eval', it is safer.
This code checked under bash 5.0.3(1).

Answer (score 1):

modern shells already support arrays( and even associative arrays). So please do use them, and use less of eval.

```
var1="this is the real value"
array=("$var1")
# or array[0]="$var1"
```

then when you want to call it , echo ${array[0]}

Comment: would this work if i get the string from commandline argument (e.g. as `$1`)?

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer of @MrZ:

Using `declare -n` you can generate a reference to any variable whose name is generated dynamically. For example:

```
$ var_one='This is variable 1'
$ ind=one
$ declare -n var_ref=var_$ind
$ echo $var_ref
This is variable 1
$ ind=two
$ echo $var_ref
This is variable 1
$ declare -n var_ref=var_$ind
$ echo $var_ref

$ var_two="And this is the second variable"
$ echo $var_ref
And this is the second variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111627

```
###############################################################################
# Summary: Returns the value of a variable given it's name as a string.
# Required Positional Argument: 
#   variable_name - The name of the variable to return the value of
# Returns: The value if variable exists; otherwise, empty string ("").
###############################################################################
get_value_of()
{
    variable_name=$1
    variable_value=""
    if set | grep -q "^$variable_name="; then
        eval variable_value="\$$variable_name"
    fi
    echo "$variable_value"
}

test=123
get_value_of test
# 123
test="\$(echo \"something nasty\")"
get_value_of test
# $(echo "something nasty")
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk is able to get the variable in a POSIX compliant and safe way if the variable is an environment variable:

```bash
export a=var var=1
awk -v a="$a" 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON[a] }' -v a="$a"
```

Eval can also be guarded like this, which will strip forbidden characters:

```bash
export a=var var=1
eval "v=\$${a##*[!0-9_a-z_A-Z]*}"
echo "$v"  # shows '1'
```

```bash
export a='(touch hacked!)' var=1
eval "v=\$${a##*[!0-9_a-z_A-Z]*}"
echo "$v"  # shows '$'
```

Comment: It's very rarely useful to answer a question that is 14 years old and already has an accepted answer (with a very high upvote count, no less).

Comment: Is arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities an exception? If not, apologies for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

I use a (relatively) short, `POSIX` compatible and execution safe way to assign a value:

```
echo -n "$var_name" | tr '\n' '#' | grep -Pq '^\w+$' &&
    eval "var_value=\$$var_name"
```

`grep` regex is very flexible and can be changed to be as strict/flexible as required for variable name validation.

The only downside is reliance on `grep` and `coreutils` (`tr`), but these utilities are guaranteed to be present in any Linux distribution minimal install.

Note. I only posted this answer because it is useful for everyone who write shell scripts on systems where /bin/sh is not a symlink to bash.

Answer (score -1):

```bash
VALUE=$(eval "echo \$$SOME_VAR_NAME")
```

Example

```bash
SSH_KEY_FILE_PATH_FOO="/tmp/key"
SSH_KEY_FILE_PATH_VAR_NAME_PREFIX="SSH_KEY_FILE_PATH"
SSH_KEY_FILE_PATH_VAR_NAME_SUFFIX="FOO"
SSH_KEY_FILE_PATH=$(eval "echo \$${SSH_KEY_FILE_PATH_VAR_NAME_PREFIX}_${SSH_KEY_FILE_PATH_VAR_NAME_SUFFIX}")
echo "$SSH_KEY_FILE_PATH"
/tmp/key
```