# Read input, save it to a dynamically-named variable and check if given input was empty

Tags: bash, variables, dynamic, zsh

Consider a generic `ask()` function that asks the user a question, reads the input and saves it in a variable named according to one of the function's arguments.

```
ask() {
    local question="$1"
    local varname="$2"

    echo "$question"
    read $varname
}
```

Suppose I want to ask the user what is his favourite pet and store the answer in a variable named `$pet`. Usage would be as follows:

```
ask "What is your favourite pet?" pet
```

What I want to do and need help with is check if the user's input was empty, and in that case set the user's input to some string. I would be able to do this easily if the name of the variable the user's input is stored in was constant, like so:

```
if [ -z "$pet" ]; then
    pet="foo"
fi
```

However the name of the variable I want to check whether or not is empty is whatever I pass in as the second argument. How can I check if the variable (named as per the value of `$varname`) containing the user's input is empty? The solution should be as portable and standard as possible, and must work under bash and zsh specifically.

Comment: This may be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921279/how-to-get-a-variable-value-if-variable-name-is-stores-as-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input thus far I managed to get a satisfying solution.

```
eval varname_tmp=\$$varname

if [ -z "$varname_tmp" ]; then
    eval "$varname=foo"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash, `${!varname}` gives you the value of the variable whose name is the value of `$varname`, but as far as I know, this syntax is not supported by zsh. If you want something that works in both bash and zsh, you may have to use the oldfashioned `eval value=\${$varname}` and then check `$value`. You should only use this if you know in advance that the value of `$varname` is a legal variable name; otherwise this is unsafe.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This made it a bit less confusing!

Comment: In `zsh`, the syntax would be `foo=bar; bar=3; print ${(P)foo}`. `eval` should only be necessary for full POSIX compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

maybe:

```
ask() {
        name=$1;shift
        read -r -p "$@ >" var
        eval "$name='$var'"
}

ask pet "What is your favourite pet?"
pet=${pet:-foo}

echo "PET: $pet"
```