# evaluating variable that comes in an array in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to read Xcode build settings via shell script, i.e. if there is a build setting called PRODUCT_NAME, I read its value by writing `echo ${PRODUCT_NAME}` in shell script.

Now, I get this PRODUCT_NAME in an array, lets call myArr having just one element PRODUCT_NAME. I loop over that array as

```
for i in "${myarr[@]}"
do
:
    echo $i 
done
```

`echo $i` would simply output PRODUCT_NAME. However, I want to write something that would evaluate ${PRODUCT_NAME} and give me results.

I have also tried `eval echo $i` but that also outputs PRODUCT_NAME only

Comment: Is the array positional (numeric indexes) or associative (text keys)?

Comment: array is positional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by using

`echo "${!i}"`

The second line gives the output as desired. I have taken this answer from here: [How to get a variable value if variable name is stored as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921279/how-to-get-a-variable-value-if-variable-name-is-stored-as-string)

Comment: You don't need the `eval`, or even a temporary variable. Just use `echo ${!myarr[0]}`.

Comment: In fact, `echo "${!i}"` is all you need inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

As I interpret your problem, You hold the array of variables, and while traversing, you want to use the actual values of the variables.

I tried the below code which is almost similar to which you have written and seems working.

```
#!/bin/bash

PRODUCT_NAME="Calendar"
PROCUCT_VER="2.3"
PROCUCT_OWNER="Sam"

PRODUCT_DETAILS=( $PRODUCT_NAME $PROCUCT_VER $PROCUCT_OWNER )

for PRODUCT_PROPERTY in "${PRODUCT_DETAILS[@]}"
do
    echo "PRODUCT_PROPERTY: $PRODUCT_PROPERTY"
done
```

Output:

PRODUCT_PROPERTY: Calendar

PRODUCT_PROPERTY: 2.3

PRODUCT_PROPERTY: Sam