# Bash - combine for loop variables and work to variables

Tags: linux, bash

In Linux Bash,

```
a1=web
a2=app
for counter in 1 2
do
a=a$counter
echo $[$a]
done
```

So,

```
$[$a]
```

How would it echo web & app?

Comment: You can use echo `${!a}`
This is introduces a level of [variable indirection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1921337/5894196).

Comment: If your variables are all `a*` and nothing else matches, then you can simplify your code to `for each in ${!a*}; do echo ${!each}; done`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash dynamic variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/bash-dynamic-variable-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying now works for *integer*-valued variables, because arithmetic expansion performs recursive expansion of strings as parameters until an integer value is found. For instance:

```
$ web=1
$ a=web
$ echo $[a]
1
$ echo $((a))
1
```

`$[...]` is just an obsolete form of arithmetic expression that predates the POSIX standard `$((...))`.

However, you are looking for simple indirect expansion, where the value of a parameter is used as the name of another parameter with an arbitrary value, rather than continuously expanding until an integer is found. In this case, use the `${!...}` form of parameter expansion.

```
$ a=web
$ a1=a
$ echo $a1
a
$ echo ${!a1}
web
```