# Increase variable count using i++ in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables

Code:

```
website="https://www.test.com/"
item_1="stuff"
item_2="more-stuff"

        while [1]
        do {
            for (i=1; $i<=3; i++)
              do {
                  echo $website$item_$i &
                  sleep 2
                 }
                 done
           }
           done
```

Output I'm getting:

```
https://www.test.com/1
https://www.test.com/2
```

Output I desire:

```
https://www.test.com/stuff
https://www.test.com/more-stuff
```

I am trying to increment the "item" variables by using $i in place of the number, so I may loop through them, but it is not giving me the desired results. Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: There is already a answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41406/use-a-variable-reference-inside-another-variable

Comment: @kcats would you be able to assist in helping me with what to put? I read it but Im not understanding what I should change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `item_x` variables and [inderect variable references](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#BASH2REF):

```
#!/bin/bash

website="https://www.test.com/"
item_1="stuff"
item_2="more-stuff"

while true; do
    for (( i=1; i<=3; i++)); do
       item=item_$i
       echo $website${!item}
       sleep 2
    done
done
```

To create the indirect variable reference, first we have to create a variable that stores the name of the variable we want to indirectly reference, hence:

```
item=item_$i
# item stores the name of the variable we want  to 
# indirectly reference, be it item_1, item_2, etc.
```

Now that we have the name of the variable we want to reference in another variable, we use *inderect reference* to retrieve not the value of the variable `item`, but the value of the variable that is stored inside that variable, that is `item_x`:

```
${!item}
```

So var `item` stores the name of the variable we want to indirectly referenced by using the `${!var}` notation.

It can be much simpler if you use an array instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

website=https://www.test.com/
items=( stuff more-stuff )

# You can refer to each item on the array like this:
echo ${items[0]}
echo ${items[1]}

while true; do
    for item in "${items[@]}"; do 
        echo "$website$item"
        sleep 2
    done
done
```

Also can try this other way:

```
#!/bin/bash

website="https://www.test.com/"
item[1]="stuff"
item[2]="more-stuff"

while true; do
   for (( i=1; i<=3; i++)); do
       echo $website${item[i]}
       sleep 2
   done
done
```

Comment: unfortunately the way i have it written in this example is a bit smaller than what i actually have, i need to have each "item" be its own variable.

Comment: @Aaron notice that you can still refer to individual items in the array like so: `${items[0]}`, `${items[1]}`, etc.

Comment: Indirect variable worked, can you explain how? its confusing me.

Comment: In a function you can use the `declare -n` to create a *nameref* variable that would accomplish the same task.

Comment: @Aaron added an explanation about _indirect variable reference_ to the answer. English is not my first language so I apologize if it is not very clear or for any spelling or grammar mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what we call indirect parameter expension `${!B}` Two others threads are speaking about it.

[How to get a variable value if variable name is stored as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921279/how-to-get-a-variable-value-if-variable-name-is-stored-as-string)

[Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)