# how to echo variable with name including $ sign?

Tags: bash

suppose two variables:
A1=1234
A2=5678

```
for i in 1 2
do
echo $A$i
done
```

it prints:

```
1
2
```

i want to print:

```
1234
5678
```

how to do that?

Comment: Try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921279/how-to-get-a-variable-value-if-variable-name-is-stored-as-string?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
for i in 1 2
do
  temp="A$i"
  echo "${!temp}"
done
```