# Getting a Bourne Shell String Variable Literal Value

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to iterate over a path to a directory to run a function on all the files. Please note that this is using the Bourne Shell (`/bin/sh`) - **NOT BASH** - as that is part of the requirements I am under.

I have found resources on:

- [Prefix/Suffix substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-loop-over-files-in-directory-and-change-path-and-add-suffix-to-filename)

  - Available with [Bourne's parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)
- [Bash literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921337)

I cannot at this time get things working. The `for` loop executes, but it is using the string version of the `basepath`, when I need it to use the literal (hence bash literals ex: `${!parameter}`; but I need it for Bourne).

Currently, I have:

```
#/bin/sh
PROJECT_NAME="Testing"
build_path=$(pwd | sed "s/${PROJECT_NAME}.*/${PROJECT_NAME}\//")
upload_folder() {
    basepath="$1/*"
    basepath="${basepath%\"}" # suffix
    basepath="${basepath#\"}"
    printf "${basepath}"
    for entry in ${basepath}; do
        echo "Entering ${entry}"
        if [ -f "$entry" ]; then
            echo "Found a file ${entry}"
            # HERE IS WHERE I WOULD RUN ANOTHER FUNCTION
        elif [ -d "$entry" ]; then
            echo "Going into folder ${entry} to upload"
            upload_folder ${entry}
        else
            echo "Nothing found"
        fi
        echo "Finished with $entry"
    done
}

upload_folder $build_path
```

I hope I can get some assistance here; really stuck on this one.

Comment: `I am trying to iterate over a path to a directory to run a function on all the files` Which files? Iterating is a mean to an end, I mean you want to run a function on each file in some directory path? This really looks like XY question.

Comment: `hence bash literals ex: ${!parameter};` What do you mean by "bash literal"? I screened [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) and I see the word "literal" only used in a literal sense. A `${!parameter}` would be called an _indirect expansion_, why do you need it in your code?

Comment: I'm looking run a function (not vital to the post; therefore not included) on each file individually. This isn't a question about doing that, it's about getting the literal value (it's using the string version) of the `basepath` variable.
Apologies getting confused on the *indirect expansion* part. I'm looking to use the literal value in the `for loop`. In some tests, I used a variable with double quotes around the path and the path itself - no quotes - in the for loop, and only the latter returned any results.

Comment: Ok. Then `basepath="${basepath%\"}" # suffix
    basepath="${basepath#\"}"` Why do you do that? What do you mean it does? `basepath="$1/*"` What's the point? Take some time and read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Answer (score 1):

I see no value in creating your own recursive function. Just get the list of all files and run your callback on it:

```
find /some/dir -type f | while IFS= read -r file; do echo yourcallback "$file"; done
```

It will be safe as long as there are no newline characters in filenames.

---

> ```
> basepath="$1/*"
> ```

Assigning `*` to a variable to do filename expansion later is always going to byte - because then you have to depend on word splitting. Do `*` on the last step.

> ```
> basepath="${basepath%\"}" # suffix
> basepath="${basepath#\"}"
> ```

Make no sense - why would your variable have quotes?

> ```
> printf "${basepath}"
> ```

Looks very strange - `basepath` is not a formatting string. Do `printf "%s\n" "$basepath"` - the first argument is formatting specifier.

> for entry in ${basepath}
> upload_folder ${entry}
> upload_folder $build_path

All unquoted variable expansions undergo word splitting, so they always will be error prone. As a rule of a thumb - always quote all expansions. Use http://shellcheck.net to find all most common mistakes in your scripts.

Just:

```
upload_folder() {
    for entry in "$1"/*; do
        # echo "Entering ${entry}"
        if [ -f "$entry" ]; then
            echo "Found a file $entry"
            # HERE IS WHERE I WOULD RUN ANOTHER FUNCTION
        elif [ -d "$entry" ]; then
            echo "Going into folder $entry to upload"
            upload_folder "$entry"
        else
            echo "Nothing found"
        fi
        echo "Finished with $entry"
    done
}
upload_folder "/tmp"
```

Comment: This is a solution to get the files yes, but I am looking at fixing the variable expansion.

To use my issue in your script, substitute `/some/dir` for my `basepath` variable.
I cannot get my script to work with the `basepath` variable after it's passed by double quotes. I have used no-quotes and quotes and neither work. I just need to get the non-string value so that I can use it in the for loop

Comment: The find command really did help when I started playing around with it Kami; thank you.

I do not believe there is a way to get this working for bash

Comment: `I cannot get my script to work with the basepath variable after it's passed by double quotes` I have no idea what you mean by that. Quotes are not preserved in variable assignment (I mean, unless they are), they are part of the syntax, with special meaning. [bash manual double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes)