# Bash variable combining into existing variable

Tags: bash, variables

Not sure how to explain this but I am trying to create a variable on the fly of an existing variable. But not sure how to explain it. I have tried many different ways bit its now about to blow my mind.

```
# existing variable
count_completed=10
count_failed=2

showCount() {
  if [ "$1" == "completed" ]; then
   echo ${1^^} count is $count_${1,,}
  fi
}

showCount "failed"
```

I've tried to create another variable and escaped the dollars and then tried echo that variable, but it didn't work

```
newvar=\$count_\${1,,}
echo ${1^^} $newvar
```

Im not sure what I'm doing wrong... :) its a very unique issue; Can't find any examples of what I'm looking for or what I should be asking for...

Comment: Maybe the verb "interpolate"?

Comment: Generally trying to do something like that is a big sign you should be using an associative array instead.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #6: "How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) and the many questions here about indirect expansion and/or nameref variables, like ["How to get a variable value if variable name is stored as string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921279/how-to-get-a-variable-value-if-variable-name-is-stored-as-string). Hint: associative arrays are almost always better.

Comment: if I do the following:
newvar=\$count_${1,,}
echo $newvar

the variable displays right variable but the error says invalid number

Comment: never mind, eval newvar .... that worked!

Comment: @Khorem `eval` should be avoided whenever possible. If you don't understand exactly how shell parsing works, it's way to easy to get bizarre and sometimes dangerous bugs with it.

Comment: @Khorem : Why aren't you using an associative array instead? It's easier to understand and IMO safer too.